# Random selection of polygons in ArcMap?

Tags: arcmap, select, random

I have thousands of buildings blocks in ArcGIS. I want to select a half of this blocks randomly.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

I would create an attribute containing a float random number in the intervall `[0...1]` and select all features with an attribute value smaller than 0.5.